# Text not wrapping inside a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I managed to use the Flexible Box Layout Module for a lot of things, however when it comes to paragraphs I'm experiencing this issue:

- When I use a small amount of text everything works as expected:

  [image]
- When I use a large amount of text the layout breaks:

  [image]

Here is the code I am using:

```css
body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 3em auto;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.title {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.image {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.image img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.text {
  flex: 6 0 auto;
  background-color: #96AED1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Title here</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/some-imgage.png">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer felis velit, ullamcorper eu ornare sed, vulputate quis diam. Duis ultrices rutrum sapien, in condimentum nibh sagittis sit amet. Morbi sit amet rhoncus dui, at pharetra nisi. Nunc et
      lacus porttitor, pretium nisl at, sollicitudin velit. Donec felis nisl, consequat vitae egestas vestibulum, egestas non tortor. Cras mattis non sem nec aliquam. Sed dignissim sit amet sapien vitae feugiat. Pellentesque vel luctus ante, quis ornare
      purus. Nulla in arcu sapien. Aenean tempor arcu ac lacinia pellentesque. Quisque vulputate maximus augue, non aliquet ligula gravida in. Donec a leo justo. Integer velit eros, blandit sit amet elit eget, efficitur mollis nulla. Suspendisse tempor
      ligula facilisis scelerisque ullamcorper. Ut vehicula ligula ipsum, cursus condimentum sapien pretium ac.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Why is the `<p>` tag not wrapping properly when using a large amount of text?

Comment: Use **.text p{flex: 6 0 auto; background-color: #96AED1; }** instead '.text {flex: 6 0 auto;background-color: #96AED1;}'

Comment: Tried, but text still not wrapping as it should.

Comment: .text p{flex: 6 0 auto; background-color: #96AED1; } just wrapped the texts inside **.text** div.It will be helpful if you fiddle or post an image how you want it to look like.

Comment: Sorry. I'm looking for this: http://i.imgur.com/tTDvdXK.jpg

Comment: You need to define width for the .text div. Just add **'.text{max-width:81%}'** (customize the width as per your need). It should be total width of body - image width (on left)

Comment: Yes, this could do it, but on windows resize it wraps. I just figure out that if I take out the initial size of the `.text` element from: `flex: 6 0 auto;` to `flex: 6 0 0;` it behaves properly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that seems to work but I do not that it is 100% correct, here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2xxorq4n/1/

And here is the CSS code:

```
body {
  width: 90%; 
  margin: 3em auto;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
section {
  border:1px solid black;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.image { 
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.image img {
  display: block; 
  max-height: 100%; 
  max-width: 100%;
}
.text { 
  background-color: #96AED1;
}
/* FLEX STYLES */
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.title, .image, .text {
  flex: 1 100%;
}
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .image { flex: 1 auto; }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .text { flex: 800 0px; }
  .image { order: 1; }
  .text { order: 2; }
}
```

Specifically, I do not think that this is correct: `.text { flex: 800 0px; }`. Although it seems to work, I do not think that it is supposed to work like that as the example on css tricks website which provides further information on Flexbox usage shows `flex: 2 0px;`:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I was replying to @CodeRomeos, I figured that if I take out the initial size of the `.text` element from: `flex: 6 0 auto;` to `flex: 6 0 0;` it behaves properly. But it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Making the flex-basis 0 nails it. `flex: 6 0 0` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 19):

The proper solution is either to put

```
white-space: initial;
```

or

```
min-width: 0;
```

Check out the link [here](https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/)

*I am aware the link is about truncating texts. However, the same solution applies to wrap the texts around.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to make the text truncate, but break.

Comment: Perhaps I should make it clearer in the answer. Thanks for the feedback @MateusFelipe

Answer (score 6):

the .text's parent has flex-direction: row, so .text should have shrink set on 1 otherwise the text inside won't wrap

```css
body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 3em auto;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.title {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.image {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.image img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.text {
  flex: 6 1 auto;  /* FLEX-SHRINK: 1; */
  background-color: #96AED1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Title here</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.macovei-sculptor.ro/img.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer felis velit, ullamcorper eu ornare sed, vulputate quis diam. Duis ultrices rutrum sapien, in condimentum nibh sagittis sit amet. Morbi sit amet rhoncus dui, at pharetra nisi. Nunc et
      lacus porttitor, pretium nisl at, sollicitudin velit. Donec felis nisl, consequat vitae egestas vestibulum, egestas non tortor. Cras mattis non sem nec aliquam. Sed dignissim sit amet sapien vitae feugiat. Pellentesque vel luctus ante, quis ornare
      purus. Nulla in arcu sapien. Aenean tempor arcu ac lacinia pellentesque. Quisque vulputate maximus augue, non aliquet ligula gravida in. Donec a leo justo. Integer velit eros, blandit sit amet elit eget, efficitur mollis nulla. Suspendisse tempor
      ligula facilisis scelerisque ullamcorper. Ut vehicula ligula ipsum, cursus condimentum sapien pretium ac.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the parents width is not set, the text will not know when to start wrapping.

Setting either the `width` or `max-width` property will let the string know when to start wrapping